# Converter string em rota

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Gostaria de salvar a rota no banco de dados.

Então salvei assim. Exemplo:

Tabela rotas

```
| id | rota |
|  1 | route( 'login' )
```

Aí gostaria recuperar e usar como rota mesmo no Laravel, no blade.php

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
<a href="{{ $rota->rotas }}">Link</a>
```

Ele mostra o texto como link e não o link da rota

```
http://localhost/route('login')
```

Será que é possível?

Converter o texto que veio do banco na rota propriamente dito?

Eu não gostaria de salvar a url mesmo, porque seu mudar a url vou ter que ir no banco, mas se for o jeito eu troco

Comment: Se salvar apenas  'login' no banco e na view <a href="{{ route($rota->rotas) }}">Link</a> não  resolveria?

Comment: Vai nao.. Ele mostrar a string

Comment: No caso você que definir uma rota no banco de dados, ou quer que consiga chamar essas rotas pelo banco de dados, por exemplo rota `login` retornaria a rota de nome login, ou ao definir essa rota no banco ela passaria a existir?

Comment: Quero salvar a rota no banco dados. Eu gostaria de chamar a rota pelo banco de dados.. Isso mesmo ao chamar login, retornaria eu poderia montar route('login')

Comment: Não entendi o porque ele vai mostrar a string. Se você utilizar o helper route('coluna do banco') deverá mostrar o que tiver lá. Ex https://implode.io/C0qPqH

Comment: Exatamente. Ele mostra o que está no banco e não rota que eu gostaria. Ex.: Se eu salvei no banco `route('login')`, e tentar colocar na url assim: `<a hre="{{ $rota }}">rota </a>` quando eu passar o cursor sobre a url ele mostra assim: `localhost://meuapp/route('login')`  não a url configurada na rota que seria essa `localhost://meuapp/login`

Comment: Use o helper route. Testa com {{ route($rota) }}

Comment: Vou pesquisar como se usa esse helper route

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de como seria.. Os que eu encontrei não resolveriam

Comment: No meu comentário anterior já havia escrito route('login'), isso  já cria a url para  o link.  <a href="{{  route($rota)  }}">CLIQUE</a>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89899/discussion-between-marcos-xavier-and-adventistaam).